# UI not updating smoothly due to a background Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am writing an android game and here is what i have:

Game loop is implemented as:

I have made a custom view which extends the view.Then inside my onDraw() method, i call invalidate();

MainActivity:

Here i make an instance of a custom view and use setContentView() to set that as my current view.
I also use OnTouch() method to get touch events

Everything was working fine and smoothly till i did this:

I made a new class Graphthread and inside the run method, i created a loop.

```
public class Graphthread extends Thread
   {
    @Override
    public void run() { 
         while(true)
       {

        }
    }
     }
```

Then i created an instance of this in my MainActivity

```
Graphthread gth = new Graphthread();
```

and used gth.start() in my onCreate method.

Now following happened:

The game did not run smoothly.Or i should say it was like..run for sometime..freeze for a few milliseconds...run again ...freeze again and so on.

What is happening?

Comment: Your thread is _executing_ an infinite loop, regardless if there is anything useful inside the loop.

Comment: I know that.It is just an experiment.I want to know what is happening.

Comment: What's happening is that your background thread is stealing CPU time from the UI thread, causing it to freeze/jitter.

Answer (score 1):

Slight jitters like that sounds like garbage collection. If your background thread (or something else) is consuming a very large amount of memory, the GC may need to run more often then expected. That would cause momentary jitters such as you described.

Comment: Thanx for the reply.But,i am not doing anything in the background thread yet. i.e while block is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try more suitable approach for games: use `SurfaceView` and background thread to draw on it. This should free you from stuttering, cased by irregular message processing by main thread.

`onDraw` hack, from my point of view, suitable only if you want to animate something inside a regular app (not game), and animation framework has little use for you. Panning and scaling image for example.